# Additive Codes: What are they? And how are they related to stabilizer codes?

Tags: stabilizer-code

I recently encountered the term "additive code" in the answer to my question here

[What are nontrivial examples of stabilizer codes whose codewords have some $\pm i$ coefficients?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/what-are-nontrivial-examples-of-stabilizer-codes-whose-codewords-have-some-pm/27597#27597)

Implicit in the answer seems to be the claim that additive codes are equivalent to stabilizer codes.

Googling "additive code" turns up things like

[Why stabilizer codes are named additive quantum codes?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/why-stabilizer-codes-are-named-additive-quantum-codes?rq=1)

and

[https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/fa05/projectreports/QECC1-report.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs191/fa05/projectreports/QECC1-report.pdf)

which again claim that additive codes are equivalent to stabilizer codes. But they don't seem to actually define what additive means. (Or for that matter what equivalent means in this setting.)

What is the right definition of additive? What do people mean when they say that "additive code is just another name for stabilizer code" (direct quote from appendix of Gottesman's thesis https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9705052.pdf)?

Comment: I am confused by the connection you make between the support of a stabilizer code and additive codes. Normally, stabilizer codes are connected with additive self-orthogonal codes over $\mathbb F_4$ (c.f. Calderbank et al. "Quantum error correction via codes over GF(4)") and equivalent to those up to phases. Moreover, I don't see why the support of a stabilizer code should be a linear subspace. In the simplest example, stabilizer states, the support is affine, e.g. for $|1\rangle$. For non-maximal codes, the support should be affine too.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich Full disclosure: I just heard about additive codes for the first time two days ago https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/what-are-nontrivial-examples-of-stabilizer-codes-whose-codewords-have-some-pm/27597#27597 I don't know what the defintion is beyond this vague answer https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/why-stabilizer-codes-are-named-additive-quantum-codes?rq=1 Basically I'm interested in the claim from the first link that somehow additive codes are equivalent to stabilizer codes. I'll update the question to better reflect this.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Have a look in the Calderbank et al. paper which I mentioned. The code spaces arise by mapping the stabilizer group to isotropic subspaces of the symplectic vector space $\mathbb F_2^{2n}$ and then mapping these to subsets of $\mathbb F_4^n$ with a suitable orthogonal structure. This mapping is not linear, so you will only get additive codes over $\mathbb F_4$ in the sense that the code spaces are only closed under addition, not scalar multiplication. The equivalence you're looking for is proven in that paper (Thm. 2)

Comment: BTW "additive code" and "linear code" are already defined in classical coding theory. "Additive code is another name for stabilizer code" is just false/misleading. There's the already mentioned connection to additive self-orthogonal codes over $\mathbb F_4$, but that's it. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21971/2305

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me add a potentially much simpler explanation here. Consider a vector space over a finite field, $V \subseteq \mathbb{F}^n_q$. These are length $n$ vectors whose elements are in $\mathbb{F}_q$. As a vector space, it is closed under multiplication by scalars, i.e., if $v \in V$, then $cv \in V$ for $c \in \mathbb{F}_q$. This is called linear. Stabilizer codes are generally not linear (not to be confused with nonlinear).

Recall that in the symplectic formulation of stabilizer codes, a stabilizer can be written in the form $(a, b)$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{F}^n_q$. The $a$ part gives the $X$ stabilizers and the $b$ part gives the $Z$ stabilizers. A more compact way to write this is as a length $n$ vector $a + \omega b$, where $\omega$ is now a primitive element for the extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}/\mathbb{F}_q$. Basically, recall that $\mathbb{F}_4 = \{0, 1, \omega, \omega^2\}$ and is not equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. In this notation we have stabilizers which are elements of $\mathbb{F}^n_{q^2}$ instead of $\mathbb{F}^{2n}_q$.

Now, consider, for example, the $[[15, 1, 3]]$ quantum Reed-Muller code with stabilizers
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega\\
0 & \omega & \omega & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega\\
0 & 0 & \omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & \omega & \omega & \omega\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega & 0 & \omega\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In this notation, a $0$ is an $I$, a $1$ is an $X$, an $\omega$ is a $Z$, and an $\omega^2 = 1 + \omega$ is a $Y$. We see this is a CSS code since the stabilizers are purely $X$ or purely $Z$. Applying any stabilizer to itself (repeatedly) is the same as vector addition in this notation. Repeated addition is the same as multiplication, so these stabilizers are closed under multiplication by $\{0, 1\}$. However, you cannot multiply a row by, say, $\omega$, because that would convert an $X$ stabilizer to a $Z$ stabilizer and vice-versa. In this sense, the code is not closed under multiplication by every element of the underlying field. It is therefore not a linear space but only an additive space (closed under addition).

Some stabilizer codes are symmetric and fully linear. Most are not. That's why they are called additive codes. These terms are essentially equivalent, but stabilizer codes are also self-dual (additive codes) under some proper inner product in order to enforce the orthogonality relationship between $X$ and $Z$.

I will add as a side-note that additive codes can give non-intuitive results. Consider a qubit stabilizer code of length $n$. The size of the total space is $2^n$. There are $n - k$ stabilizers, so all possible combinations give a subspace of size $2^{n - k}$. The code therefore has dimension $\log_2(2^n / 2^{n - k}) = \log_2(2^k) = k$. When you go to qudit systems with more complicated finite fields, you get expressions such as $q^n / p^{n - k}$, which may or may not be an integer (here $q = p^m$ and $p$ is the characteristic of the field). This suggests such a code can encode a non-integer number of logical operators. Due to this, classical additive codes are usually expressed in a different symbol then the standard linear notation $[n, k, d]$ that people are used to. This causes a lot of unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer a brief answer for now as I don't have much time today. Much of this material is from a friend's lecture notes. Feel free to ask more questions if you need further clarification.

I'll represent the group action of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ as $G \curvearrowright V$ and the invariant subspace of $V$ under this group action as $\mathrm{Inv}_G(V) := \{v :  gv = v \ \forall g \in G\}$.

If $V = \mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space and $G \curvearrowright V$ is a unitary action and $G$ acts by isometries for a [quantum metric](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0353) then the subspace $\mathrm{Inv}_G(\mathcal H) \subseteq \mathcal H$ is called a **stabilizer code** in general. The exact definition of a quantum metric is a bit involved; for starters, you can check the first two pages of the Weaver-Kuperberg paper that I linked, or I can explain it later if you wish.

The point now is that if the quantum metric under consideration is the quantum Hamming metric and $G$ is the [multi-Pauli group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Multi-qubit_Pauli_matrices_(Hermitian)) then $\mathrm{Inv}_G(\mathcal H_n) \neq 0 \iff \text{$G$ is abelian}$. Then $\mathrm{Inv}_G(\mathcal H_n)$ is *an example* of what is called **additive code** (not the definition!). In the QCQI community, there's a tendency to conflate this with the notion of general stabilizer codes. Well, partly due to the way Gottesman et al. and subsequently Nielsen & Chuang described it in their papers and books. If you're having confusion about terminology, rest assured that you're not alone. :-)

The word "additive code" originally comes from classical coding theory. In full generality, a code $\mathcal C$ is a subset of a space of messages $\mathcal X$, i.e., $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal X$, equipped with a metric $d(.,.)$, carefully chosen to allow for detection and correction of errors. One major issue with this fully general case is that if you choose a radius $r$ ball around any arbitrary codeword $C \in \mathcal C$, you're not guaranteed to have an equal number of messages within each such ball. (By the way, if you need a refresher on classical coding theory, check [Wootter's lectures](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Emarykw/classes/CS250_W18/index.html).)

To symmetrize this scenario and to make analysis easier, a simplifying assumption is that $\mathcal X$ is abelian group and $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal X$ is a subgroup, s.t., $d(x, y) = d(x + z, y + z) \ \forall x, y, z \in \mathcal X$ or equivalently $||x|| := d(x, 0)$ so $d(x, y) = ||x - y||$. This means the metric is chosen to be translation invariant. It is this condition that allows us to correspond the abelian group structure and the metric structure -- a norm is an abelian case of a translation invariant metric. Such a code $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal X$ is an **additive code**. Yes, this is the definition that you were looking for.

For example, the usual [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) is a metric that is clearly translation invariant, so we can see the Hamming distance comes from a Hamming norm, a value equal to the Hamming weight $||x||$, or in other words, the number of $1$s appearing in an $x \in \mathcal X$.

Furthermore, if $\mathcal X$ is equipped with a vector space structure, then it is possible for $\mathcal C$ to be a subspace (and thus, be a [**linear code**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code)). We can then expect a relation between $||x||$ and $||\lambda x||$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb F$ (the underlying field of the vector space $\mathcal X$). The Banach relation $||\lambda x|| = |\lambda|.||x||$ is appropriate when say $\mathbb F = \mathbb C$ or $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ but it doesn't make much sense here. If $\mathbb F = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ or any finite field, we can instead take the Hamming relation that $||\lambda x|| {=}_{\lambda \neq 0} ||x||$. That is, we treat all non-zero scalars in the same way, or effectively take there to be no relation. We do not need to have an axiom concerning scalar multiplication
because if $\mathcal C$ is an additive code then $\mathcal C$ must be a linear code. For the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, linear and additive codes are the same.

Here's a useful theorem. **Theorem**: If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathcal C \subseteq V$ is a subgroup, then it is a subspace. You should note that this theorem is false for fields other than $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

The point is that if a metric space $\mathcal X$ is finite, abelian and normed (as is the case if $\mathcal X$ is a Hamming space) then the balls of the same radii $r$ have the same cardinality:

$$|B(x, r)| = |B(y, r)|$$

where $x$ is the ball center and $y$ is the ball radius. This is a reflection of the translation symmetry of a group law, and in such a scenario, analysis of the code becomes much simpler.

Comment: You mention that $ Inv_G(\mathcal{H}_n) $ is an example of an additive quantum code.  And you define a classical additive code on $ n $ bits as a subgroup/subspace of $ \mathbb{F}_2^n $. Could you clarify for me what it means for a code to be additive in the quantum case? Something about a translation invariant metric? And for the difference between additive and linear are you saying that linear just means the norm is both translation and scaling invariant? Thanks for your long answer and offer to clarify. I appreciate it.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira To answer your first question, indeed, it has to do with a translation invariant metric on $\mathcal M_2(\mathbb C)^{\otimes n}$ (the [von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra) on $n$ qubits). In the quantum case, an *additive code* arises when we use the *quantum Hamming metric* and the group $G$ is taken to be the *multi-Pauli group*. Like the classical Hamming metric, the quantum Hamming metric is also translation invariant. You'll find the exact definitions on page 2 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0353).

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira To answer your second question, a *linear code* is defined as a subspace $\mathcal C$ of a vector space $\mathcal X$. We know that when we want to induce a norm from a metric $d(.,.)$ on a vector space, the metric $d$ [must satisfy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3386603) translation invariance and a scaling property. A general metric on a vector space need not satisfy these properties. However, if we want an additive code, which by definition requires a translation invariant metric, we can have a norm induced from the vector space metric. For example, the Hamming metric.

Comment: The definition of **additive code** is this: A subgroup $\mathcal C$ of an abelian group $\mathcal G$, equipped with a translation invariant metric that induces a norm given an appropriate scaling property, *or equivalently*, equipped with a norm that automatically induces a translation invariant metric. That is what is meant by a norm being an abelian case of a translation invariant metric.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an additive quantum code and an example of a non additive quantum code and explain how the difference can be determined based on your definitions? For example you could specify which $ \mathcal{G} $ and $ \mathcal{C} $ you are working with. I am aware that in the cases I am interested in $ G $ is the multi qubit Pauli group. What is the abelian group $ \mathcal{G} $? Is it the same as $ \chi $ from your answer above? Are $ \chi $ and $ \mathcal{G} $ abelian subgroups of the multi Pauli group? How does one pick the subgroup $ \mathcal{C} $ in a common example?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira No, $\mathcal G$ need not be related to the multi-Pauli group in general. Yes, $\mathcal G$ is the same as $\mathcal X$ that I used in the answer, except only in the cases where $\mathcal X$ has an abelian group structure. The issue is that QCQI people usually only deal with the multi-Pauli group, but in full generality, you don't necessarily need to. For example, check [Nice Error Bases](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0010082). OTOH, there are plenty of examples of additive codes in classical coding theory literature, for example [this](https://bit.ly/3vTF1ou).

Comment: "Could you provide an example of an additive quantum code and an example of a non additive quantum code and explain how the difference can be determined based on your definitions?" It's a good question but it's getting too long for the comments section. I may not have much time this week, but you can ask it in a separate thread. The point is that any example of quantum additive/non-additive code will respect the definitions that I gave above. You'll need to do some work to show it though.

Comment: Ya I wasn't expecting you to put an example in the comments, better to edit it into your answer. After all, every good explanation comes with an example! As for the nice error bases stuff and exotic choices of $ \mathcal{G} $ that's cool, seen it in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608049 but I'm really looking for a much less exotic example; as a sanity check for your definition I want to make sure it includes stabilizer codes. For example what choice of $ \chi $ and $ \mathcal{C} $ reproduce the [[5,1,3]] code? And I'm aware of classical additive codes, no need to provide more references!

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira These are all good questions. I'm not inclined to edit my answer any further at this point, but you're welcome to ask these as new questions in separate threads. Even if I don't get time to answer them, someone else might.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for your lengthy answer and comments. I appreciate all the time you put into this!